# How to convert string of array to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I use ajax and jquery
and I have an array String that echoes from php

```
data = "{"user_id":"1","name":"phanith kung","last_date":"2015-06-08 00:00:00"}"
```

How do I do this?

I tried to use
`data.user_id`

but it's doesn't work.

Comment: This is a string of an object, not an array. If it is valid as an object (seems so), you can use JSON.parse(data) to get a proper object.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"user_id":"1","name":"phanith kung","last_date":"2015-06-08 00:00:00"}')
```

then

```
obj.user_id
```

Comment: The code won't compile with double quotes inside of a double-quoted string. Consider changing double quotes to single quotes (around the JSON string) or escaping double quotes.